# Receive email only when all the tasks are completed

Tags: sungridengine, qsub

I am launching a lot of jobs on a cluster as an array (similarly to what explained in http://www3.imperial.ac.uk/bioinfsupport/help/cluster_usage/submitting_array_jobs)
If I use `$ -m ea` I receive hundreds of emails, one for job.

How can I receive an email only when all the tasks are completed? Is it possible to receive when all the tasks are completed but also an email when any of the task is aborted?

Comment: Err, don't ask for them until you're ready to receive them?

Comment: the flags for asking email notification is set at the moment of the array submission, and they are applied to each job of the array..so either you receive no mails, or hundreds of mail. What I want is to receive only 1 mail at the end. What should I set?

Comment: I would try using job arrays (-t option), but I haven't tested whether this would send only one email for the job, or one email for each task. Job arrays where designed to group together related tasks. They also take load off the queue master.

Comment: Yes, actually the -t option is what I am using at the moment, and in my case I am receiving a mail for each task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my knowledge, this does not seem possible. Others may have more experience, so I defer *final* solution to those with more experience.

However, what you can do is:

1. Submit your job array **without** the `-m` option (or with `-m a` to track aborted tasks)
2. submit a second single *dummy* job using `-hold_jid_ad <job_id_of_job_array>` and `-m e` option.

This will send email when hold on on single job (step 2) is satisfied i.e. when all tasks in your job array complete (step 1).

Comment: I had to use -hold_jid  <job_id_of_job_array>  and in my test it worked, thanks!  With -hold_jid_ad I got "can only specify  hold_jid_ad option with an array job"

Comment: I like so much this solution that I am thinking to unify and post-process the data with the "not-anymore-so-dummy" job

Comment: Cool! I think that's the idea. I did same for my analyses e.g. do analysis using job array (or multiple single jobs), and use `hold_job_id` on job that compute summary statistics on entire data set or makes plots.